# Python standard library function for rearranging a list

Tags: python, list, function, standards

I am wondering if there is a standard library function in Python which will rearrange the elements of a list like below:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

function(a)

print a

a = [1,7,2,6,3,5,4]
```

It should get one element from beginning of original list, then one from end, then second from beginning and so on. Then rearrange the list.

Regards,

Comment: Why on earth would anyone have created this as a standard library function? Are you looking for a domain-specific languages for generating sestinas?

Comment: That's a very specific way to reorder a list. I highly doubt there's a standard library function to do exactly that. Fortunately, you can just write one.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no _standard_ function to do what you have asked. You could use list comps. it'd be pretty minimal

Comment: Python is a programming language, not a massive prebuilt collection of every conceivable program.

Comment: @alwbtc: eknath means *[list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could build a fast, memory efficient [generator](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) using [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) which does what you want:

```
from itertools import chain, izip

def reorder(a):
    gen = chain.from_iterable(izip(a, reversed(a)))
    for _ in a:
        yield next(gen)

>>> list(reorder(a))
<<< [1, 7, 2, 6, 3, 5, 4]
```

You'll find that `itertools` has a great collection of building blocks for creating your own efficient iterators. A slightly more succinct solution:

```
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(izip(a, reversed(a))))[:len(a)]
<<< [1, 7, 2, 6, 3, 5, 4]
```

[List comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) are another really concise way to build lists:

```
>>> [x for t in zip(a, reversed(a)) for x in t][:len(a)]
<<< [1, 7, 2, 6, 3, 5, 4]
```

Finally here's a short one-liner just for fun:

```
>>> sum(zip(a, a[::-1]), ())[:len(a)]
<<< (1, 7, 2, 6, 3, 5, 4)
```

Comment: Nice! Why not `gen = chain(*izip(a, reversed(a)))`, though?

Comment: Yeah, that's better actually, since `reversed` returns an iterator.

Comment: Yeah but after that I broke down :(

Comment: Happens to the best of us.  :-)

Comment: `*izip` isn't memory efficient, it has to expand the iterators all at once. You want `chain.from_iterable(izip(a, reversed(a)))`.

Comment: thanks! But I had written my own function, please look: def shake(list):
    """Gets a list and reorders the items,
       one from beginning, one from end"""
    #print "original list is: ", list
    new_list = []
    
    x = len(list) - 1
    y = len(list)/2
    
    for i in xrange(y):
        if list[i] not in new_list:
            new_list.append(list[i])
        if list[i+x] not in new_list:
            new_list.append(list[i+x])
        x -= 2
        
    if len(list)%2 == 1:
        new_list.append(list[y])
        
    #print "new list is: ", new_list 
    return new_list

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> ((a+a[:0:-1])*len(a))[::len(a)][:len(a)]
[1, 7, 2, 6, 3, 5, 4]
```

Comment: Astonishing. But ``(a+a[:0:-1])*len(a)`` has a length of 91 elements if len(a)==7, and a length of 19900 if len(a)==100

Comment: @eyquem, Of course it's not efficient, but this q did set off my homework radar

Answer (score 2):

```
for a in ([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
          [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
          [1,2,3,4],
          [1,2,3],
          [1,2,],
          [1],
          []):
    print a
    [ a.insert(i,a.pop()) for i in xrange(1,len(a)+1,2)]
    print a,'\n'
```

result

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 9, 2, 8, 3, 7, 4, 6, 5] 

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 8, 2, 7, 3, 6, 4, 5] 

[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 4, 2, 3] 

[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 2] 

[1, 2]
[1, 2] 

[1]
[1] 

[]
[]
```

### Update 1

Comparing to zeekay's code:

```
from time import clock


n = 100000


te = clock()
for i in xrange(n):
    a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
    [ a.insert(i,a.pop()) for i in xrange(1,len(a)+1,2)]
print clock()-te



from itertools import chain, izip
def reorder(a):
    gen = chain(*izip(a, reversed(a)))
    for _ in a:
        yield next(gen)

te = clock()
for i in xrange(n):
    a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
    a = list(reorder(a)) 
print clock()-te
```

result

```
2.36667984339
5.00051766356
```

My method changes **a** in place

Answer (score 2):

Of course in Python there is only ever one way to do things ;-):

```
def function(a):
    ret = []
    this_end, other_end = 0, -1
    while a:
        ret.append(a.pop(this_end))
        this_end, other_end = other_end, this_end
    return ret

a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

print function(a)
```

For timings:

```
% python -m timeit 'def function(a):
quote>     ret = []
quote>     this_end, other_end = 0, -1
quote>     while a:
quote>         ret.append(a.pop(this_end))
quote>         this_end, other_end = other_end, this_end
quote>     return ret
quote>
quote> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
quote>
quote> print function(a)
quote> ' | tail
[1, 7, 2, 6, 3, 5, 4]
[1, 7, 2, 6, 3, 5, 4]
[1, 7, 2, 6, 3, 5, 4]
[1, 7, 2, 6, 3, 5, 4]
[1, 7, 2, 6, 3, 5, 4]
[1, 7, 2, 6, 3, 5, 4]
[1, 7, 2, 6, 3, 5, 4]
[1, 7, 2, 6, 3, 5, 4]
[1, 7, 2, 6, 3, 5, 4]
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.5 usec per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks all, I have written my own function:

```
def shake(list):
    """Gets a list and reorders the items,
       one from beginning, one from end"""
    #print "original list is: ", list
    new_list = []

    x = len(list) - 1
    y = len(list)/2

    for i in xrange(y):
        if list[i] not in new_list:
            new_list.append(list[i])
        if list[i+x] not in new_list:
            new_list.append(list[i+x])
        x -= 2

    if len(list)%2 == 1:
        new_list.append(list[y])

    #print "new list is: ", new_list 
    return new_list
```